# Unable to launch STS 3.7.0 for windows

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I've download the latest release from spring.io, nothing changed, and launch failed. I'm under Windows7, and permission is given Everyone.
The log file is attached, thanks!

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.confluence.ui 2 0 2015-07-08 13:17:17.999
>
> !MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.confluence.ui [664]
>     Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.core; bundle-version="2.0.0"
>       -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.core; bundle-version="2.5.0.v20150522-1430"; singleton:="true"
>          org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.core [666]
>            Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.discovery.ui 2 0 2015-07-08 13:17:17.999
>
> !MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.mylyn.discovery.ui [644]
>     Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime
>       -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="3.11.0.v20150405-1723"; singleton:="true"
>          org.eclipse.core.runtime [153]
>            Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
>              -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="3.7.0.v20150330-2103"; singleton:="true"
>                 org.eclipse.core.jobs [148]
>                   Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-07-08 13:17:18.003
>
> !MESSAGE Application error
>   !STACK 1
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:78)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)

Comment: Might be your OS bit problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you problem is the message:

```
Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))
```

which means you need to run Eclipse with Java 7 (or 8)

Comment: Yes, you are right... My jdk is 1.6. After I installed jdk1.8, and I forgot to configure the jre path to the right location, after then, everything goes right. Thank you!